# .htaccess post data

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have set up my .htaccess to point to index.php on a 404 error
`ErrorDocument 404 /index.php`
the index.php will return a 404 if the url is not a page in the database, otherwise it displays the correct page.

How can I get any $_POST data sent here as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get $\_POST query when 404 redirected through .haccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396886/how-to-get-post-query-when-404-redirected-through-haccess)

Comment: Are you sure that the data is not there? I don't think that an `.htaccess` rule like this would destroy data... could be wrong though...

Comment: Why would you post to a page that could be missing? You have control over your FORM, how can this happen?  Do you have a use case?

Comment: You can catch non-existent files with a `RewriteCond !-f` though.

Comment: Mario - looks like , sorry had found similar questions but not this one
Lix & Emartel - the data appears if action="index.php" but I have set up the system to pull apart the URL to find the current page and want to drop forms on any page and return results to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Thanks to Mario for putting me on the right path.