# Post raw data empty in ErrorDocument

Tags: php, apache, post

I'm trying to develop a handler for virtual paths in Apache 2.4.2 and PHP 5.4.5 (loaded as a module), using the `ErrorDocument` directive:

```
<Directory "...">
    ...
    ErrorDocument 404 /handler.php
    ...
</Directory>
```

As far as the used method is GET or HEAD, it all works like a charm. Troubles come when the method is POST.

When using POST, in my test PC I manage to get the input stream via `file_get_contents('php://input')`, even when the `Content-Type` header is set to `multipart/form-data`. In the server PC, the content is *always* empty, even when the type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I'm trying to get the raw POST data because `$_POST` and `$_FILES` are empty when the script is the result of this kind of redirection.

Is there something I'm missing? Maybe some different setting in the httpd.conf file? The php.ini file is the same. I just don't know where to begin.

**UPDATE**: it seems the difference was due to the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element I was using for testing purposes. Looks like the script is able to get the raw POST data when the `action` is set to a `.php` file *and* it's located in the root directory.

I guess this has something to do with the `AddHandler` directive used in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: After server redirecting there is no post data available.

Comment: @EL2002 Too bad. But it seems that in *some* cases the raw post data is actually available. But it also seems that I can't rely on that...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396886/how-to-get-post-query-when-404-redirected-through-haccess which explains how to use mod_rewrite to do this