# how to append a query string to error document

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, redirect

Is there any to to capture query string and append it to error document (404). Something like:

Requested page:

```
http://www.example.com/sdsdsd
```

Redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/404.php?pg-name=sdsdsd
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ErrorDocument in the htaccess configuration, you could force a real redirect to the error.php like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /error.php?pg-name=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

Source: [How to get `$_POST` query when 404 redirected through .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396886/how-to-get-post-query-when-404-redirected-through-haccess)

In the error.php page you can then check, if the pg-name parameter is given to the error.php:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';
```

If you call you page like this: http://domain1.com/asdasdasd (assuming the link is not found), the output from the error.php will look like this:

```
Array
( 
    [pg-name] => /path_to/public_html/asdasdasd
)
```

Then you can get to the requested string "asdasdasd".

Comment: I am using this 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /404.php?pg-name=$1 [L,R]
but the problem is that it is not setting header to 404 rather setting the header to 302

Comment: "force a real redirect" - Note that this is an _internal rewrite_, not an _external "redirect"_. This is good, you don't want to "redirect" (`R` flag on the `RewriteRule`) the request, otherwise the user will be sent a 3xx status. However, you will need to manually set the appropriate 404 HTTP status code in `error.php`.