# How to convert Blazor WebAssembly IIS rewrite rules to Apache mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, iis, mod-rewrite, blazor-webassembly, url-rewrite-module

Having created an example Blazor WebAssembly application, I deployed it to both an IIS and an Apache for testing purposes.

When publishing the application, it generated a folder "wwwroot" and a file "web.config":

[image]

The "wwwroot" folder contains the whole application:

[image]

When deploying to IIS, everything works fine.

What I'm currently struggling with is to deploy to Apache.

The "web.config" file contains two rewrite rules.

Rule 1:

```xml
<rule name="Serve subdir">
    <match url=".*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Rule 2:

```xml
<rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
</rule>
```

I've tried several things to get at least rule 1 working with mod_rewrite, like e.g.:

```conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*?$ /wwwroot [QSA]
```

But I either get 404 or endless redirects.

#### My question

How to convert above rule 1 and rule 2 to Apache mod_rewrite configurations?

---

#### Update 1

I do think this one is a valid replacement for rule 1:

```conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /wwwroot/$1 [L]
```

I've got it from [this Super User answer](https://serverfault.com/a/907902/54658).

#### Update 2

[There is a Microsoft documentation on how to host on Apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly#apache) but it is missing the rewrite parts.

#### Update 3

Based on the above Microsoft document, I was able to resolve it:

1. Do *not* put the "wwwroot" folder into the root folder of the Apache website.
2. Instead, place the *content* of the "wwwroot" folder directly into the root folder of the Apache website.
3. Do not put any mod_rewrite rules at all to the ".htaccess" file.
4. Add this directive to the ".htaccess" file:

   ```conf
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
   ```

The complete, minimal ".htaccess" file for my test application looks like this:

```conf
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html

AddType application/wasm .wasm
AddType application/octet-stream .dll

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/octet-stream
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/wasm
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

#### Update 4

Above example was for running the Blazor WebAssembly application directly from the root folder of an Apache website.

If you instead want to run it from a subfolder (let's say "/myappinfolder") some things have to be changed:

1. Move all files, including the ".htaccess" file, into the subfolder "myappinfolder".
2. Modify the `ErrorDocument` directive in the ".htaccess" file to:

   ```conf
   ErrorDocument 404 /myappinfolder/index.html
   ```
3. Change the base href in the "index.html" file to:

   ```html
   <base href="/myappinfolder/" />
   ```

#### Update 5

Instead of using the `ErrorDocument` Apache directive, another option is to use the [`FallbackResource` Apache directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) instead:

```conf
FallbackResource /myappinfolder/index.html
```

The `FallbackResource` has the advantage that it keeps the HTTP method (e.g. `POST` or `GET`) when forwarding the request to the configured URL ("/myappinfolder/index.html" in my example).

Whereas `ErrorDocument` always forwards the request to the configured URL ("/myappinfolder/index.html" in my example) with a `GET` HTTP method.

(Idea from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43682826/107625))